# Prototype hasclassname issue

Tags: javascript, prototypejs, dom-events

I have a ul list :

```
<ul id="menubar">

<li onclick="ajx=new Ajax.Updater('container','schedule.php',{evalScripts:true,onComplete:oncom(this)})">one</li>
<li onclick="ajx=new Ajax.Updater('container','schedule.php',{evalScripts:true,onComplete:oncom(this)})">two</li>
</ul>
```

Here is the function callback:

```
 function oncom(element){
            //$(element).addClassName('current');
            $$('#menubar li').invoke('observe', 'click', (function(element) {
  //removes classname from all the li elements
  // 
  var list_item = Event.element(element);



  //Gets the li you clicked on


  //adds the classname
  if(!(list_item.hasClassName('current'))){
  list_item.addClassName('current');
  }else{
  $$('#menubar li').invoke('removeClassName', 'current'); 
  }

}).bindAsEventListener(this));
            }
```

But its not making the current link having affect of that class, but when I click on next link its takes affect. How to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

The options you are passing to the updater are `{evalScripts:true,onComplete:oncom(this)}`. You are not assigning the function `oncom` to `onComplete` but calling `oncom(this)` straight away then assigning it's result to `onComplete` - and the result is null.

If `container` contains the menubar list then it will also be replaced (probably why you are recreating click handlers). Consider using [`Event.on`](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/Event/on/) once so that newly inserted elements behave correctly.

```
Event.on('container', 'click', '#menubar li', function(event, element) {
    // manipulate class names here
});
```

Also consider that if all you're doing is manipulating class names you can do that on the server when AJAX is used, that will avoid race problems.

Answer (score 0):

The reason its not working until you click the first item is because the oncom function contains the observe for the li elements, and you're not running that code until you click on one. You need to get rid of the onClick stuff in the html if possible. Just run this code when the page load, and it will observe the li's straight away:

```
$$('#menubar li').invoke('observe', 'click', (function(e) {
    //Removes current class from all the li's
    $$('#menubar li').invoke('removeClassName', 'current');
    //Add current class to the li clicked on
    Event.element(e).addClassName('current');
    //Does whatever this does, without being in the onClick
    new Ajax.Updater('container','schedule.php',{
        evalScripts:true
    });
}).bindAsEventListener(this));
```